# how to start mocha tests asynchronously on node.js + Express.js + mongodb app

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, tdd, mocha.js

Problem seems very trivial so I am really embarrassed that I can’t solve it on my own but I did a lot of search on google and stackoverflow and nothing helped me yet.  I am developing RESTful server with node.js and I want to test it’s API. Server initialize asynchronously (it needs to connect to db, to request token from another server etc.). So code in my server.js file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var bunyan = require('bunyan'); // logger
var routes = require('./routes/folrouter.js');
var TokenGetter = require('./utils/tokengetter');


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fol', function (err, db)
{
    if (err)
        throw err;

    global.db = db;
    global.log = bunyan.createLogger({
            name : "folserver",
            src : true,
            serializers: bunyan.stdSerializers,
            streams : [ {
                path : 'folserver.log',
                type : 'file'
            } ]
        });


    global.log.info("folserver starts...");
    var tg = new TokenGetter();
    tg.on("token_received", function(token){
        global.access_token = token;
        global.log.info("access_token received: " + token);
        //TO DO: compression and cache static content
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true } ));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use('/api', routes);
        app.listen(8080);
        console.log('Express server listening on port 8080');
    });
    tg.getToken();

});

//only for tests!!!
module.exports = app;
```

I defined script actions in my package.json file so I can run tests from command line with “npm test” command:

```
{
  "name": "folserver",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Server side for my app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
   ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "should": "^4.3.0",
    "supertest": "^0.15.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha   --require should  --reporter spec  --ui bdd  tests/tests.js",
    "start": "server.js"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "author": "PainKiller",
  "private": true
}
```

And then I have tests.js with following code:

```
var should = require('should');
var request = require('supertest');
var app  = require('../server.js');
describe("user.js", function () {
    describe("#upsert()", function () {
        it("should insert new user object correctly", function () {
            before(function (done) {
                console.log("before");
                request(app)
                .post('api/user/upsert', user)
                .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                .end(function (error, res) {
                    done();
                });

            });

            after(function (done) {
                //after
                console.log("after");
                done();
            });

        });

        it("should update new user object correctly", function () {
            //Test Goes Here
        });
    });

    describe("#isregistered()", function () {
        it("should return false on id not in db", function () {
            //Test Goes Here
        });

        it("should return true on id in db", function () {
            //Test Goes Here
        });
    });
});
```

First problem - my app initializes completely after tests starts - I see it with console.log outputs from my app when I am starting “npm test”. And I see my tests passed in console (they do nothing at that point, except  first, but it passed too) Second – I’ve never see console.log outputs from my tests in my console – and it’s really freaks me out, may be this code never runs? But if it’s true, how can I see results of my tests in console?

I see two ways to solve it. First – make delay before starting tests, I’ve tried  --timeout command with mocha – it doesn’t helped. Till now I can’t find a proper and nice way to stop execution of JS code for a period of time. Second – to emit event with app, and to start tests on that event, but I’ve failed with this way either. And maybe I am wrong with something else, I just didn’t see it, so I appreciate any help and comments. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally managed problem with initializing my app before tests. This is final code:

```
var should = require('should');
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../server.js');

//this is root level hook  with setTimeout do the trick
before(function (done) { console.log("before all"); this.timeout(9000); setTimeout(done, 5000); });

describe("user.js", function () {
    describe("#upsert()", function () {
    before(function (done) {
                console.log("before 2");
                this.timeout(5000);
                var user = { test: "test" }
                request(app)
                .post('/api/user/upsert')
                .set('Content-Length', JSON.stringify(user).length)
                .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                .send(user)
                .end(function (error, res) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    console.log(res);
                    done();
                });
                //done();
            });

        it("should insert new user object correctly", function (done) {
            console.log("it");
            //console.log(app);
            //console.log(global.db);
            done();

        });
        after(function (done) {
            console.log("after");
            done();
        });

        it("should update new user object correctly", function (done) {
            //Test Goes Here
            done();
        });
    });

    describe("#isregistered()", function (done) {
        it("should return false on id not in db", function (done) {
            //Test Goes Here
            done();
        });

        it("should return true on id in db", function (done) {
            //Test Goes Here
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works asynchonously and I see all console.logs in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

Call test function with a callback parameter. [Mocha will then run this function asynchronously](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

EDIT:
Just reorganize your hooks in your case.

```
describe("#upsert()", function () {

    var result;

    before(function (done) {
         console.log("before");
         request(app)
         .post('api/user/upsert', user)
         .set('Accept', 'application/json')
         .end(function (error, res) {

             result = res;
             done();
        });

    });

        after(function (done) {
            //after
            console.log("after");
            done();
        });

    it("should insert new user object correctly", function () {

        // assert "result" object here
    });

    it("should update new user object correctly", function () {
        //Test Goes Here
    });
});
```

Because you had "before()" inside a non asynchronous function. it() would exit not waiting for before() to finish. Place async preparation function outside or call it() as an asynchronous function itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I am trying to implement your advise, and first thing I saw  - all log traces disapeared, and I still can't see console.log from my tests. Can't figure out what does it mean.

Comment: And server endpoints still not work I suppose because they aren't initialized